# Check to see if a string contains a combination of another string

Tags: javascript

I have a string that I'd like to fuzzy match on, I've tried using ES6 includes but it doesn't seem to match the conditions where I'd like it to.

```
const station = 'virginia square-gmu george mason university'
```

When I do the following I end up getting false even though all of the words are included inside of station.

```
station.includes('virginia square george mason university')
> false
```

What would be the correct way to see if `station` includes any combination of the words passed into the includes statement, would RegEx be a good candidate for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the words into an array and use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check that each word is contained within the string.

```js
const station = 'virginia square-gmu george mason university'
const words = 'virginia square george mason university';

const all = words.split(' ').every(word => station.includes(word));
console.log(all);
```